# Getting ridge skeleton using watershed transform with Python

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image, watershed, image-morphology

I'm currently trying to translate a code that was originally written in IDL to Python and have gotten completely stuck on a part of the code that uses the [Watershed](https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/watershed.html) function from IDL to get the 'ridge skeleton' (so-called by the original writer of the code) of an image. See example images below of the input and results.

Input image
[image: Input image]

Result
[image: Result]

The line of IDL code that produces this reads

```
result = watershed(image, connect=8)
```

Unfortunately I know nothing about using watershed etc but from what I can tell with OpenCV or scikit-image you need to call a lot more than just the image itself? I see things like markers being mentioned for example. The `connect=8` part I'm guessing is related to nearest neighbours but I don't know how to go about implementing this in any of the Python packages I've come across.

I cannot seem to replicate the output given by IDL so I was hoping someone with a bit more expertise than me might recognise that kind of result and be able to point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be a normal watershed. The watershed creates a region around each local minimum in the image. Sad that the [OpenCV watershed function](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga3267243e4d3f95165d55a618c65ac6e1) only does marker-based watershed. You'd have to find the local minima and use those as the markers.